# Are watermarks constrained by the quality of the underlay video?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, resolution, video-encoding, watermark

This may be a stupid question but I have to clarify it for my own peace of mind, so bear with. The good news is it's more or less a yes/no question for the FFmpeg/AV experts who know the answer.

Say I have a low-resolution source video eg. 320x240, and a PNG watermark image that was actually produced this decade, so at least double that resolution and high-quality.

If I use FFmpeg to overlay the PNG on top of the video, is it unavoidable that the quality of the PNG will be limited to 320x240 pixels, being constrained by the resolution of the video... or should it be possible for it to look sharp and high-quality (i.e. like it has all its original pixels) even while the rest of the video does not? If it's the latter case, then I'm probably just doing something wrong in my experiments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be small & crunchy.

You don't even need to test this empirically. Your output resolution is 320x240, any & all elements within that will also have that maximum pixel count - or considerably fewer in the case of a watermark tucked in a corner.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I suspected. My logic was that there might be some obscure way to make it work because it's an *overlay* over the source video with its own resolution, but I suppose it's getting encoded to the same low-res video stream in the end. Thanks for the prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

Tetsujin's answer is of course still the correct answer to the question and will remain accepted, but I also found that there's a workaround you can use if you need to have a watermark retain its quality in a low-res video - upscaling the video itself.

Because upscaling doesn't actually do anything to significantly degrade the original video, by definition only adding information (albeit bumping up the file size in the process), this means it's possible to first upscale the video stream to a resolution that's higher than that of your watermark image (eg. 960x720p), and then overlay the watermark on top of it.

The original video will look no worse, and the watermark will look as the designer intended it to, since it now has enough pixels in the video stream to work with... or at least, I found this was the case was for my source videos.